# Facebook getloginurl additional permissions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I just try to update to PHP SDK 4.0. I can't find my mistake and hope you can help me. I copied all files to the folder "./facebook4" and implemented following code:

```php
// Skip these two lines if you're using Composer
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', '/./facebook4/src/Facebook/');

// if you include this file you don't need to use composer
require __DIR__ . '/./facebook4/autoload.php';

// include required files form Facebook SDK
require_once( './facebook4/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( './facebook4/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( './facebook4/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( './facebook4/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( './facebook4/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );
require_once( './facebook4/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( './facebook4/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( './facebook4/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( './facebook4/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( './facebook4/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( './facebook4/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( './facebook4/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( './facebook4/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( './facebook4/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( './facebook4/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('AppID','secretAppID');

$redirect_url = "http://www.mypage.de/Logged.php";

// use the helper 
$facebook = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
// get a loginurl


$permissions = array(
'email',        
'read_stream',
'user_actions:criminalcase'
); 

echo "Test1";
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($permissions);
echo "Test2";

echo "<a href='".$loginUrl."'>Link here</a>";
```

Test1 is displayed when I call the page but Test2 and the "Link here" are not displayed. So I guess there must be a problem with getLoginUrl but I have no idea what it is

Comment: Check your error log

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/

Take a closer look at the array:

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);
```

So in your case, it should be like this:

```
$permissions = array(
    'scope' => 'email, read_stream, user_actions:criminalcase'
);
```

Not sure what you want to achieve with "user_actions:criminalcase", there is no such permission. Also, you don´t need all those require statements when using the autoloader.

Important: You will most likely not get `read_stream` approved, so it will only ever work for users with a role in your App (Admin/Developer/Tester):

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need read_strea and user_actions:criminalcase to read the postings that were made from the facebook games on the user's wall. With the old SDK it was no problem to get these permissions and reading the postings. If they changed this now, what else are the correct scope for being able to read the game-postings like from criminal case or farmville?

Comment: I looked abit around on that page and I found 2 other scopes that I maybe could use instead of read_stream, if I understand it correct: user_games_activity and user_actions:{app_namespace}. Can anybody tell me the difference?

Comment: BTW I changed the source code to: 
$permissions = array(
    'scope' => 'email, read_stream, user_actions:criminalcase'
); but the result is still the same, Test2 isn't displayed

Answer (score 0):

There is still problem in your syntax.

try this

```
$permissions = array('email', 'read_stream', 'user_actions:criminalcase');
```

I am not sure about your "user_actions:criminalcase" permission.

But I have corrected here the syntax.